# How do you prevent a flame war?

Tags: discussion

So, I have [this question from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963793/excel-formula-to-check-cell-contents) about some persnickety MS Excel constraints I couldn't (then or now, if I were still trying) get around. I'm pretty sure that I made a clear case in the original post, and clarified a couple questions about it in comments, consistent with a pattern I've seen many, many times (and followed) here. Then, I got a bunch of answers that didn't read the question all the way through, and told them so. (I am, admittedly, not the world's most patient respondent when it comes to reading comprehension on a site that [it seems to me] depends on it.)

A few days ago, I get [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25171273/409856), and since I have (I hope understandably) moved on from the problem in the "interim", I point out an immediate error or two previously indicated on the thread, get told that the specifics aren't the answerer's problem, so go back and check for about 2 minutes, and realize the answer is totally incorrect, so downvote. Now, said poster is flagging the question, hiding my responding comments, etc.--basically lording reputation over me. (I am a poster who admittedly asks more questions than I answer, and often long-winded ones that go unanswered, their quality notwithstanding in this context, so I don't carry much weight in this.)

Sorry for the blow-by-blow drama, but, in a search for canonical resources, how does one stop this from getting out of control, without rewarding the absolute incorrectness of the post that brought this other contributor and I together after so many years?

Comment: "(I am, admittedly, not the world's most patient respondent when it comes to reading comprehension on a site that [it seems to me] depends on it.)" Don't worry. None of us is.

Comment: Point out the error in a comment then move on with your life and ignore it. If your comment is correct it will likely receive a fair amount of up-votes over time and readers will take it seriously. The best way to stop a flame war is to remember that the outcome doesn't actually affect you, and also to give other readers' discretion a little bit of credit. In most cases you're probably not going to convince the other of your point of view anyways (and do you really *need* to?), and third-party readers *certainly* don't care to watch the war, so there's not really much point to it.

Comment: @BoltClock It appears downwitch is being serially downvoted now, just enough to escape the script maybe.

Comment: I think as far as starting flame wars go, you put more fuel on the fire than the other person did.  If the question is still important to you, consider taking some of the advice given about more specific examples, tighten up the question (huzzah adds nothing), and offer a bounty.

Comment: @Daedalus: The script ran a couple of hours ago, so we'll just have to wait until tomorrow. downwitch, feel free to flag one of your posts if the votes have not been invalidated and you'd like someone to look into it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm not saying I'm blameless, but I would point out that the OP was written when I was relatively new to SO, and when I think the general tone (however well I understood it) was a little looser. I can't easily add more specific examples now because I haven't worked on the problem in over three years.

Comment: Your comments ("my bad (and yours) for not checking your work", "More concrete examples?", "Where is your thorough proof that it works and is thought through?") sound rather condescending to me. If you don't want to start a flamewar, I would advise to change the tone of your comments.

Comment: @dirkk I hear you. I'm not trying to condescend--it's more frustration than anything. I agree that I should be more diplomatic.

Comment: Someone flames you, don't flame back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an answer that attempts to comprehensively answer "How do I prevent a flame war?" So I post guidelines both on blow-by-blow comment flame wars, and for dealing with trolls doing damage over voting, closing questions, etc.

#### Dealing with flame wars in discussions

This site is relatively good at preferring facts and agreed norms of relevance to Godwin's law and derivative discussion. I'm not saying this is a formula, but these are some guidelines that have let me get pretty involved in an antagonistic technical discussion without flat out diverging into a flame fight:

- Always respond and only respond to points of technical merit.
- Take technical points that are trolls seriously. "Well why don't you just rewrite *everything* in C?" just answer succinctly saying "That wouldn't be cost-effective."
- You don't have to go into detail if you feel it's a waste of time. "If someone reading this really feels rewriting everything in C is okay, that's their business, but in my opinion it's very unusual, so I'm not going to discuss that direction right now."
- If the discussion goes in a circle do not redo your points. The snarkier answer is "As I explained two comments above..." and the more closed is "We're repeating, I'd like to leave these comments as a resource to future visitors and exit this discussion here."
- If you feel something is off-topic, say so. At most verbose, "I don't feel that's relevant to the point at hand, and while it's interesting would rather not discuss it now." If off-topic happens repeatedly, "These points are off topic, so I'd rather end this discussion here."

Which can boil down to the following principles:

- Technical points only.
- Remember you are writing for a technical audience trying to learn. They don't care who's winning or trolling or whatever.
- Cut it off when you feel it's too troll-ish or circular by being honest that you don't want to continue.

I usually continue these discussions up until technical points of merit are no longer made.

#### Dealing with trolls heckling with your participation

If the troll escalates, there's two main cases:

- Is it an isolated flag, downvote, close vote, etc.? If so, just let it go. Your losing 2 reputation is probably not worth an intervention. Offensive speech is an exception; flag this.
- If it's a pattern, you will probably want to escalate to a moderator.

  - Even in a case of a well-meaning but perhaps stubborn person, if there's an edit war, stop re-editing and flag for moderator attention.
  - If you are being attacked and having posts flagged, close-voted, etc., flag and explain the person is attacking you.
  - *Serial downvoting is an exception*. It's usually auto-detected and reverted within 24 hours, so give it 24 hours before flagging for moderator attention.
  - If the comments get sufficiently out of line (racist, threatening, hateful, etc.), flag. But if it's just an annoying / stubborn / mildly disrespectful argument, it's better to handle on your own and just stop engaging.

Comment: Thank you, those are helpful guidelines. I'm not sure this thread is well titled or explained (since if the back-and-forth had occurred in 2010 I would have been better prepared to Just Be Technical, and with the lapse of time, fairly or no, sort of resent the unhelpfulness), so if something can be done to make it more useful to M/SO users, I'd appreciate your revision(s).

Comment: @downwitch it's not very rigorous. If this answers your question and you don't find anything really wrong or objectionable, accept it. If you want to leave the question open to see if you get better answers, go with that. Beyond that, just whichever one you like or find most useful, as long as you found one that answers it.

Comment: @djechlin Calling troll someone who doesn't share your same opinions/ideas isn't that mature. Is this a trend?

Comment: @SufiDeveloper I'm not referring to people who don't share your opinions/ideas. Presumably those people will take much less finesse to have a decent conversation with, although I suppose when heated / bordering into flames this advice applies perfectly well. I'm referring to trolls.

Comment: @SufiDeveloper I tend to lump together trolls / flamers, although they're different and trolls are more of a subset of flamers. Flamers are regular debaters after things have lost their cool. Anyway this is a near-technicality, since both groups are out-of-bounds of polite discourse.

Comment: @user10089632 I haven't followed SO policy in the last few years, so I'm not the person to ask.

Comment: @djechlin, I apologize I mistaken you for working as a moderator.